# Web service consumption with oAuth2

Tags: c#, service-reference, dynamics-business-central

AS you will see, I'm not an expert developing webApps, but I've done one that connects with the web services of Business Central (BC).
Inside visual studio, I added the web service as a service reference, and the authentication is user/password. This is how the call to the WS is done:

```
protected void ValidateEmployee()

    {

        var appSettings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;

        string user = appSettings["user"].ToString();

        string pswd = appSettings["pswd"].ToString();

        string WHS_MGMT = appSettings["WHS_MGMT"].ToString();

        string ItemTRacking = appSettings["ItemTRacking"].ToString();



        WHS_MGMT ws = new WHS_MGMT();

        ws.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(user, pswd);

        ws.Url = WHS_MGMT;

        String codOperario = txtCodigo.Text.ToUpper();

        string userPswd = txtPSWD.Text;

        if (ws.Login(codOperario, userPswd))

        {

            Response.Redirect("Default.aspx?codOperario=" + codOperario);

        }

        else

        {

            lblOpIncorrecto.Text = "Operario/contraseña incorrecto";

            lblOpIncorrecto.Visible = true;

        }

    }
```

But in nest weeks, we will be forces to use oAuth2 authentication to call BC web services. I've found several tips to get the token, and at first, doesn't seem to be a problem (at first...). But he main problem is that I don't know how to apply or use that token into the call to the WS. I even don't know it adding the WS as a service reference is the best way to do it...

Any tip will be realy welcomed

Thank you all

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How can I use oAuth2 authenetication within a service reference in c#?

Comment: UPDATE: I already have a function to get the token. How can I use the credentials with the token?